# Statement "is" is false in an operation that should return true

Tags: python

I've been banging my head with the following code...

```
code = (404, 200)

if code[0] is 404:
    print "yes"

if code[1] is 200:
    print "yes"
```

should return true both right? but  just the condition of the number 200 and true why?

Comment: Use `==` for comparison, not `is`

Comment: `is` tells you if they're both the same object. Python can decide to have duplicate objects or not depending on its whims, if the objects are immutable.

Comment: @TerryA He easily could, but the point is to understand why this is happening, not just avoid the problem.

Comment: @William PY -5 - 256 are cached in python. 404 isn't, so they have different id's which `is` is testing for object identity. Try printing out id(code[0]), id(code[1]) and id(200), id(404)

Comment: @nog642 Yes, hence the closure